# Sequelize create group by bucket arrays

Tags: sequelize.js

Lets say I have 5 column in a table users

```
   name            email              state          isOnline            createdAt
| Name1 |   | name1@gmail.com |     | Kerala    |   | true  |    | 2022-08-17 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name2 |   | name2@gmail.com |     | TamilNadu |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name3 |   | name3@gmail.com |     | Karnataka |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name4 |   | name4@gmail.com |     | Karnataka |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name5 |   | name5@gmail.com |     | Karnataka |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name6 |   | name6@gmail.com |     | TamilNadu |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
| Name7 |   | name7@gmail.com |     | TamilNadu |   | false |    | 2022-08-16 10:05:32.755215+05:30 |
```

I need to combine these result into group of bucket Arrays using sequalize ORM similar to mongodb $bucket. So I'd have something like this:

```
{
    states: [
        {
            name: 'TamilNadu',
            count: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'Karnataka',
            count: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'Kerala',
            count: 1
        }
    ],
    isOnline: 1,
    isOffline: 6,
    createdAt: [
        {
            name: 'withinADay',
            count: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'withinAWeek',
            count: 7
        },
        {
            name: 'withinAMonth',
            count: 7
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't no how to achieve this. Guide me to create expected query so that i have a filter option in application.

Comment: Firstly obtain this data with common query (you need in 3 queries) which uses common or conditional aggregation. Then pack obtained data to JSON.

Comment: Problem is I'm having more than 26 fields to create buckets. Is there any other way to create buckets using single query instead multiple query.

Comment: *Is there any other way to create buckets using single query* Yes. Use conditional aggregation over the whole data, without GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, there are window functions for this problem.

Seems like window functions are not supported in Sequilize: [Issue Link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4273)

So the problem can be solved with sub-queries or sending multiple queries and combining them

This is my `node.js` solution. It gives the expected result, can be cleaned and optimized more:

```javascript
// States
const states = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    ["state", "name"],
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('state')), 'count']
  ],
  group: "state"
})

// Online status
const onlineCounts = await User.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: ["isOnline"],
  group: "isOnline"
})

const [isOnline, isOffline] = [onlineCounts.count[0].count, onlineCounts.count[1].count]

// Custom logic for createdAt calculation
const createdAtRanges = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('age', sequelize.col('createdAt')), "date"]
  ]
})

let createdAt = [
  { name: 'withinADay', count: 0 },
  { name: 'withinAWeek', count: 0 },
  { name: 'withinAMonth', count: 0 }
]

createdAtRanges.forEach(range => {
  let days = range.dataValues.date.days ?? 0
  if (days <= 1) createdAt[0].count++
  if (days <= 7) createdAt[1].count++
  if (days <= 30) createdAt[2].count++
})

res.json({ states, isOnline, isOffline, createdAt })
```